# Angular js:split date and time parameters in angular ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am displaying some data in `ng-repeat` from this i want to display date as three parameters

1.Date
2.Month
3.Time

I will get the date as a single string  `2016-05-13 16:08:33`

```
<div class="list-expense-menu-item" ng-repeat="notification in notifications">
  <h2>{{notification.text}}</h2>
  <span>Date:{{notification.notif_date}}</span>
</div>
```

Expected

```
<span>Month:05</span>
<span>Date:16</span>
<span>Time:16:08</span>
```

How to split single date to three parametes ??

Answer (score 3):

The best way about it would be to transform your notification data before displaying it. You can use regular expression for it or just parse your date and then use date methods.

```js
angular.module('app', []);

angular
  .module('app')
  .controller('Example', function ($scope) {
    const inputData = [
      {text: 'some text', notif_date: '2016-05-13 16:08:33'},
      {text: 'some text', notif_date: '2017-06-13 18:28:33'}
    ];
  
    $scope.notifications = inputData.map(({text, notif_date}) => {
      const regexp = /^\d{4}-(\d{1,2})-(\d{1,2})\s*([\d:]*)$/;
      const matched = notif_date.match(regexp);
      
      return {
        text,
        month: matched[1],
        date: matched[2],
        time: matched[3]
      };
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Example">
<div class="list-expense-menu-item" ng-repeat="notification in notifications">
  <h2>{{notification.text}}</h2>
  <span>Month:{{notification.month}}</span>
  <span>Date:{{notification.date}}</span>
  <span>Time:{{notification.time}}</span>
</div>
</div>
```

Example with Date, cos your string can be easily parsed by new Date().

```js
angular.module('app', []);

angular
  .module('app')
  .controller('Example', function ($scope) {
    const inputData = [
      {text: 'some text', notif_date: '2016-05-13 16:08:33'},
      {text: 'some text', notif_date: '2017-06-13 18:28:33'}
    ];
  
    $scope.notifications = inputData.map(({text, notif_date}) => {
      const date = new Date(notif_date);
      
      return {
        text,
        month: date.getMonth() + 1, //+1 because in JS months are numbered 0 - 11, so January is 0 and so on 
        date: date.getDate(),
        time: date.getHours() + ':' + date.getMinutes()
      };
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Example">
<div class="list-expense-menu-item" ng-repeat="notification in notifications">
  <h2>{{notification.text}}</h2>
  <span>Month:{{notification.month}}</span>
  <span>Date:{{notification.date}}</span>
  <span>Time:{{notification.time}}</span>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller modify the notif_date like this.

```
 notifications.forEach(function(notification){
   notification.notif_date = new Date(notification.notif_date);
 })
```

and try angular date [filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date) in the view.

```
  <span>Month:{{notification.notif_date | date:'MM'}}</span>
  <span>Date:{{notification.notif_date | date:'dd'}}</span>
  <span>Year:{{notification.notif_date | date:'yyyy'}}</span>
```

Comment: I assumed you are using javascript Date(). Lets try this in the controller
notification.notif_date = new Date(notification.notif_date) and let me know if it works or not.